# Check if a form input exists

Tags: javascript

I want to check if an input tag named "field2" exists when the user is filling out input name "field1". I do that by executing a JavaScript function using the `onchange` event on field1's `input` tag. (I'm testing using alert boxes.) If field2 does not exist, JavaScript clicks a button and the form is updated to have both field1 and field2. But the alert box pops up even when field2 exists no matter which of the 3 methods I use. I tried all sorts of combinations using `if` with `null` and `'undefined'`, etc.

Why do the alert boxes pop up if field2 exists ?

```js
function foobar(){

if(!document.getElementsByName("field2"){
alert("foobar");
}

if(!document.forms[0].field2){
alert("foobar");
}

if(!document.forms[0].elements.namedItem("field2"){
alert("foobar");
}
}
```

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ including your HTML code.

Comment: Btw, your code is not completely correct, but I cannot reproduce the behaviour you see. If `field2` exists, no alert shows up: http://jsfiddle.net/jS7dT/. You have to provide more information...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, the problem was that the page had various forms and therefore `forms[0]` was not referring to the form I wanted. So I think the best way is to use `this` and refer to the `input` field directly. Also, it is clearer to compare to `undefined` rather than `!`.

This works:

```js
function foobar(fooform){
    if (fooform.field2 === undefined) {
        alert("foobar");
    }
}
```

Called like this:

```js
foobar(this.form);
```

Comment: and it has to be fooform.field2, the old with(fooform) { if(field2) ...} will throw an error that field2 is not defined.

Comment: piggybacking on this one,
    `if (fooform.field2 != undefined) {
        alert("foobar");
    }`
for anyone else who reads this, make sure you're not using `fooform.field2.value` or referencing any other attributes, because that won't work.

Answer (score 6):

You are missing a bracket: `if(!document.getElementsByName("field2"))`

Comment: Also on `if(!document.forms[0].elements.namedItem("field2")`

Comment: It takes a village... or something like that :p

Comment: If these where the problems, the alert box would not appear at all, since these would be syntax errors. Since the OP gets alerts, this is unlikely to solve the problem. Probably just typos here.

Comment: Yes, it is just a typo, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

```
var element = document.getElementsByName("field2");
if(typeof(element) == 'undefined' && element != null)
{
// Field exists
}
else
{
// then field does not exist
}
```

Comment: What does this do?

Comment: Checks if a HTML field, within a page exists.  Useful when discovering if the input field is hidden and thus perform a different action.

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: This code looks wrong. Should be != 'undefined' iirc

Comment: Matty No, the code is not wrong.  I am looking for a undefined, NOT a defined.

Comment: This is not working, it will allways go into "Field not exists" part.
document.getElementsByName returns a "NodeList", so its never 'undefined' nor null

Comment: folks, it works...what can I say.  Still working today.